# PHP AJAX, return multiple values in realtime in a for loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

What I have:

```
    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
        $this->StocklistMailer($contact, $weekOrDay, $data, $content, $itemGroup);
    }

    return new Response('completed', 204);
```

What I would like is :

```
    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
        $this->StocklistMailer($contact, $weekOrDay, $data, $content, $itemGroup);
        return new Response($contact->getEmail, 204);
    }

    return new Response('completed', 204);
```

And it returns to a AJAX call on the page, the reason I want to accomplish this is because I want realtime feedback to whom it has send an email to.

Comment: Collect all emails in an array and pass it to client vai json.

Comment: Sounds like you want [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).

Comment: AFAIk you can only return one response at a time, so either collect the data and return an array or do the for loop in javascript and make the ajax call for every contact. Nevertheless, this is **no realtime** solution. You should look into different approaches like Websockets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send multiple responses from your application, the whole idea is that you only generate one response.

However, you can put all the information you require in one response.

```
$emails = [];
foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
    $this->StocklistMailer($contact, $weekOrDay, $data, $content, $itemGroup);
    $emails[] = $contact->getEmail;
}

return new Response(json_encode($emails), 200);
```

Note that I changed `204` (No content) to `200` (OK).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to break it into multiple calls;

First call will return the array of contacts which you will store in your JavaScript array. (assuming you are using Client Side JS/Ajax to call this php file).

Then loop through the array and make as many calls to php as many contacts are in your array while passing each contact at a time to php.

You can show fancy progress bar as you are looping through the array :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but not from Symfony. Look into ReactPHP, Ratchet and related technologies.

- https://blog.wyrihaximus.net/2015/03/reactphp-sockets/
- http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

You can create a websockets server that would listen on localhost for messages from your Symfony application and will be redirecting them using websockets to the browser.

The cliend would open a websocket connection to your websockets server, and send the request to your application. While the application is processing, it is sending the progress to the websocket server using a socket on the local machine. The client should be getting the progress realtime from the websocket and should be displaying it.

This way, you get a realtime interactive interface, with a long-running process.

Even better would be creating a [rabbitmq worker](https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle), that would be sending the emails and reporting the progress to the websockets server. You would create the task for the worker from your Symfony application, and therefore you wouldn't be limited by the execution time limit for php requests. Another win with the rabbitmq worker is that you can have only one (or as many as you like), and therefore the tasks will queue and you won't be burning server resources by 50 processes generating and sending emails at once.